# Php generating divs, then hiding all the divs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

Everything works except for the `hide` portion. I'm simply trying to hide each `div` as it is being generated, and I need to get control of the `div`s as well. So I'm guessing that the `div id` part is very wrong when I'm trying to increment. Please help!

```
<?php
$counter=0;
foreach ($foo as $key => $value){
$counter++;
?>

<div id="ad<?php $counter;?>">
<?php include("showPage.php");?>
</div>
 <script>$("#ad<?php $counter;?>").hide();</script>

<?php 
}
 ?>
```

Second part of question:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#FooButton").click(function(){
if($('div#ad1').is(':visible')){
$("div#ad1").hide();
$("div#ad2").show();
}

});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to echo out the value of `$counter`.

Here:

```
<div id="ad<?php echo $counter;?>">
  <?php include("showPage.php");?>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ad<?php echo $counter;?>").hide();
  });
</script>
```

**Update:**

After looking at the above solution, I cannot recommend you calling `$(document).ready()` in a loop.  A more efficient solution to this would be to add style `display: none` to the generated `div` and not use the javascript here, like follows:

```
<div id="ad<?php echo $counter;?>" style="display:none;">
  <?php include("showPage.php");?>
</div>
```

Comment: it still will not hide the divs

Comment: @Petro, I've updated my answer with a better solution than executing the `document.ready` call within a loop.

Comment: This worked! Now how would i call the div back using javascript/jquery? Would i make a css class for each element to display none then remove it? I'll update my question with what im trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you need to `echo` the value like this

```
echo $counter;
```